# Rails/Mailer - NoMethodError after sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I'm fairly new to Rails, so this will likely end up being something obvious; however I've just spent the better part of a day pulling my hair out over this issue.

I have a rails app which I've been working on for awhile, however I only started implementing mailers today. I followed the Rails ActionMailer tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.3/action_mailer_basics.html and the mailer works fine in a new example app. However, when I repeated those steps verbatim in my existing rails app (running in Development environment) I receive the below error. It creates the entry in the DB, correctly sends both the plain text & HTML emails and THEN generates the error. All I'm trying to do here is send a welcome email upon the creation of a new account, but I'm getting the same error when I try to send any email from any controller.

The specific error I'm seeing after it sends the welcome email is:

```
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 280ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass):
  app/controllers/musers_controller.rb:52:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/musers_controller.rb:50:in `create'
```

*Note that to not mess up my existing User table, I created a temporary scaffold & mailer called Muser which I plan on deleting once I'm confident this will work correctly on my user table.*

## Code

#### Error in log:

```
Started POST "/musers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-10 20:32:34 -0400
Processing by MusersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OuoEmsjkAVBHZwqPO5b/O4eKw6iZBaLP6vUT6f9WCOI=", "muser"=>{"name"=>"New User", "email"=>"User@email.com"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "musers" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 11 Jul 2013 00:32:34 UTC +00:00], ["email", "User@email.com"], ["name", "New User"], ["updated_at", Thu, 11 Jul 2013 00:32:34 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered muser_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered muser_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 280ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `error' for true:TrueClass):
  app/controllers/musers_controller.rb:52:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/musers_controller.rb:50:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.3ms)
```

--I should note that lines 50 & 52 of the musers_controller (where this error is being generated) correspond to the 'respond_to do' & 'MuserMailer.... .deliver' lines in the controller code below.--

#### The controller action:

```
# POST /musers
  # POST /musers.json
  def create
    @muser = Muser.new(params[:muser])

respond_to do |format|
  if @muser.save
    MuserMailer.registration_confirmation(@muser).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to @muser, notice: 'Muser was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @muser, status: :created, location: @muser }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @muser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
```

#### Mailer:

```
class MuserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "EmailAddress@Inter.net"

  def registration_confirmation(muser)
    @muser = muser
    mail(:to => muser.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

---

I don't think that the issue is with my smtp, mail setup, or variables since it does actually add to the DB & send the emails correctly. If I comment out the line in the controller which calls the mail action the error disappears, so I don't think the problem is with my muser routes. This  **undefined method 'error' for true:TrueClass** is driving me nuts. I did recently install Devise on my Users table, so I don't know if that could be causing the issue?

For lack of a better term, it *feels like* the issue is with how Rails wants to route after sending the emails; as if I need to put a Return or specify a route at the end of my mailer action telling the server to head back to the controller action. In other words, I'm lost!

### Update

Below are the two mailer view files I'm using.

#### registration_confirmation.html.erb

```
<h3><%= @muser.name %>! You sweet sweet fool!</h3>
<p>Thank you for registering!</p>
```

#### registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
Thank you for registering!
```

### Update 2

Here's my model for Muser:

```
class Muser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

end
```

Comment: please attach `muser_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb` and `muser_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb`

Comment: Thanks @okliv, I just updated the post with both files.

Comment: Hi, can you try turning this off in your environment? 

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

Just to check whether it has any effects

Comment: Hey @DevDude, just tried it & restarted the server but alas I'm still seeing the exact same error message.

Comment: And if you try to send this mail from console, what happens?

Comment: hmmm... in code you provided everything is correct, so the problem is somewhere else. is it possible to share all app files? or try to localize the row causing error and share it with us

Comment: First, I'd remove `@muser = muser` from your `registration_confirmation` method. Instead of using 'musers', you should take advantage of version control (git) to test new functionality before merging into your project. `error` is likely being called on your model, somewhere here: `redirect_to @muser` or `json: @muser, status: :created, location: @muser`. What happens if you don't redirect, and just render an inline response: `render inline: 'Success!'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! @Michael, I attempted this from console and was hit with the exact same error message.

Comment: @Damien, I'm using a git branch to test this, but went with musers over users because I'm just that paranoid... I'm a newb with little confidence. But I tried both removing the `@muser = muser` line from `registration_confirmation` & `render inline:''Success!' over the existing redirects and it is still giving me the exact same `NoMethodError (undefined method '`error'' for true:TrueClass):` error, and referring to the Controller line which calls `MuserMailer.registration_confirmation(@muser).deliver`

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted code snippets in that last comment - clearly I'm new to this! I can't tell you how much I appreciate all this help!

Comment: I updated my original post with the Muser model as well, just in case that could be causing the issue. @okliv unfortunately I can't share all the app files, but I'd be happy to share as much as possible if you wouldn't mind helping me localize the row causing the error. I haven't been able to find any further info in the logs than what I've shared already!

Comment: Hi all - I stumbled across the solution to my problem! Following some other set of intrustions I had added the line 'config.action_mailer.logger = true' to my 'config/environments/development.rb' file. I commented that out and everything works perfectly! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue - there was the errant line `config.action_mailer.logger = true` in my `config/environments/development.rb` file that was causing the issues. Once removed everything worked perfectly.